# script for reporting incompatible with script for calculations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am absolutely stumped, I have been working on this for weeks and have come to the conclusion that my knowledge is too limited to figure this out

ok, I have a page in my customer portal where employees can enter end of day sales reports. The first half of the page is input fields with dollar amounts and profits calculated by a percentage. Funny thing is it works on my website but not on jsfiddle.

the second part is a devices sold section using selects and calculations for price, cost and profit

there are 2 parts to the script and it gets crazy when I put them together, they dont work at all

I tried to post the entire page and script here but it was too long

here is the script

```
    function Adder() {
    var ppc = parseFloat(document.form.ppc.value);
    var tmo = parseFloat(document.form.tmo.value);
    var cf = parseFloat(document.form.cf.value);
    var act = parseFloat(document.form.act.value);
    var fla = parseFloat(document.form.fla.value);
    var misc = parseFloat(document.form.misc.value);
    var exp = parseFloat(document.form.exp.value);
    var prof1 = parseFloat(document.form.prof1.value);
    var prof2 = parseFloat(document.form.prof2.value);
    var prof3 = parseFloat(document.form.prof3.value);
    var prof4 = parseFloat(document.form.prof4.value);
    var prof5 = parseFloat(document.form.prof5.value);


    var result1 = ppc * 0.12;
    document.form.prof1.value = result1.toFixed(2);

    var result2 = tmo * 0.015;
    document.form.prof2.value = result2.toFixed(2);

    var result3 = cf * 0.21;
    document.form.prof3.value = result3.toFixed(2);

    var result4 = act * 35;
    document.form.prof4.value = result4.toFixed(2);

    var result5 = fla * 60;
    document.form.prof5.value = result5.toFixed(2);

    var result6 = ppc + tmo + cf + prof4 + prof5 + misc - exp;
    document.form.sum1.value = result6.toFixed(2);

    var result7 = prof1 + prof2 + prof3 + prof4 + prof5 + misc - exp;
    document.form.total1.value = result7.toFixed(2);
}
var item = document.getElementById('item');
var item1 = document.getElementById('item1');
var item2 = document.getElementById('item2');
var item3 = document.getElementById('item3');
var item4 = document.getElementById('item4');
var item5 = document.getElementById('item5');
var item6 = document.getElementById('item6');

item.onchange = function () {
    price.innerHTML = "$" + this.value;
    cost.innerHTML = "$" + (this[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value2'));
    qty.value = 1; //Order 1 by default.
    add();
};
qty.onchange = function () {
    add();
};
item1.onchange = function () {
    price1.innerHTML = "$" + this.value;
    cost1.innerHTML = "$" + (this[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value2'));
    qty1.value = 1; //Order 1 by default.
    add();
};
qty1.onchange = function () {
    add();
};
item2.onchange = function () {
    price2.innerHTML = "$" + this.value;
    cost2.innerHTML = "$" + (this[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value2'));
    qty2.value = 1; //Order 1 by default.
    add();
};
qty2.onchange = function () {
    add();
};
item3.onchange = function () {
    price3.innerHTML = "$" + this.value;
    cost3.innerHTML = "$" + (this[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value2'));
    qty3.value = 1; //Order 1 by default.
    add();
};
qty3.onchange = function () {
    add();
};
item4.onchange = function () {
    price4.innerHTML = "$" + this.value;
    cost4.innerHTML = "$" + (this[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value2'));
    qty4.value = 1; //Order 1 by default.
    add();
};
qty4.onchange = function () {
    add();
};
item5.onchange = function () {
    price5.innerHTML = "$" + this.value;
    cost5.innerHTML = "$" + (this[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value2'));
    qty5.value = 1; //Order 1 by default.
    add();
};
qty5.onchange = function () {
    add();
};
item6.onchange = function () {
    price6.innerHTML = "$" + this.value;
    cost6.innerHTML = "$" + (this[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value2'));
    qty6.value = 1; //Order 1 by default.
    add();
};
qty6.onchange = function () {
    add();
};



function add() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

    var total = 0;
    var taxes = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
        var sum = 0;
        var price = (parseFloat(selects[i].value)) ? parseFloat(selects[i].value) : 0;
        var cost = (parseFloat(selects[i][selects[i].selectedIndex].getAttribute('value2'))) ? parseFloat(selects[i][selects[i].selectedIndex].getAttribute('value2')) : 0;
        var qty = (parseFloat(inputs[i].value)) ? parseFloat(inputs[i].value) : 0;

        sum += (price - cost) * qty;
        total += sum;

        if (i === 0) {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "$" + sum.toFixed(2);
        } else {

            document.getElementById('result' + i).innerHTML = "$" + sum.toFixed(2);
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

and the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LFbTB/3/) for everything together, I just cant figure it out

Comment: I had this problem today as well.
JSFiddle doesn't support the onchange="function()" syntax for some reason.
The way to get around it is to use the jquery syntax $(selector).on("chnage",function() {  function here })

Comment: you can go and look at the page with the reporting section working. click [HERE](http://www.gomowireless.com/sales.php). if you put a dollar amount all of the items in the left hand side, PagePlus, T-Mobile, etc, you'll see that it al gets calculated on the right side fine, but then go down to the device section and select an item for each row, and you'll see it is calculating from inputs in the top section, and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: I tried working on this all night, and still could not get it figured out

If someone could please have a look at this at [here](http://www.gomowireless.com/sales.php) and tell me whats wrong